# Rails Authentication user and password stored on different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am working on a project, i need to have different type of users, some will be admins and others will be just users, i have a model for all users, and i have a model "login" where i would store an ecrypted password. The problem is, i create the user, and it saves on the database, but the model where the password should be stored is empty...
I tried to make assossiation on both user and login controller, and both models as well.

Ask me for the code you need to see and ill post it here.

this is my user.rb code

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :requisitions
      has_many :historics
      has_one :login
      belongs_to :rank
      belongs_to :sub_unit
      belongs_to :user_type
      #attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :salt, :encrypted_password

      validates :nim, :posto_id, :apelido, :nome, :telefone, :sub_un_id, :tipo_util_id, presence: true
      validates :email, format: { with: /@/ }
      validates :nim, uniqueness: true
      validates :password, :confirmation => true
      validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

      # Encrypting calls for new user's password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      after_save :clear_password

      # Authentication process for user's login
      def match_password(login_password = '')
      encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(login_password, salt)
      end

      def self.authenticate(nim_as_login = '', login_password = '')
        user = User.find_by_nim(nim_as_login)
        if user && user.match_password(login_password)
          return user
        else
          return false
        end
      end

      # Encrypting process for new user's password
      private
      def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
          self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.encrypted_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
      end

      private
      def clear_password
        self.password = nil
      end

    end
```

This is my login.rb code

```
    class Login < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user

      attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :salt, :encrypted_password

      #validating fields
      validates :user_id, :password, presence: true
      validates :password, confirmation: true
      validates :password, length: { in: 6..30 }

      # Encrypting calls for new user's password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      after_save :clear_password

      # Authentication process for user's login
      def match_password(login_password = '')
        encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(login_password, salt)
      end

      def self.authenticate(nim_as_login = '', login_password = '')
        user = User.find_by_nim(nim_as_login)
        login = Login.find_by_user_id(user.id)
        if login && login.match_password(login_password)
          return login
        else
          return false
        end
      end

      # Encrypting process for new user's password
      private
      def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
          self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.encrypted_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
      end

      private
      def clear_password
        self.password = nil
      end


    end
```

this is my users controller code

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :save_login_state, only: [:new, :create]

      def new
        @user = User.new
        @ranks = Rank.all
        @types = UserType.all
        @unit = SubUnit.all
        @logins = Login.all
        @page_title = "LoginUser | Novo"
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params, login_params)

        #LoginsController(:password, :password_confirmation)

        @ranks = Rank.all
        @types = UserType.all
        @unit = SubUnit.all
        @logins = Login.all
        if @user.save
          flash[:notice] = "Bem vindo #{@user.apelido}, sua conta foi criada com sucesso!"
          redirect_to sessions_path
        else
          @user.errors.full_messages.each do |e|
            if e == "Nim has already been taken"
              flash.now[:error] = "Este Utilizador já está registado!"
            else
              flash.now[:error] = "Corrija os campos do formulário!"
            end
          end
          render 'new'
        end
      end
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @ranks = Rank.all
        @types = UserType.all
        @unit = SubUnit.all
        @logins = Login.all
      end

      private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:id, :nim, :posto_id, :apelido, :nome, :telefone, :telemovel, :email, :sub_un_id, :tipo_util_id)
      end

      def login_params
        params.require(Login).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :user_id )
      end

    end
```

this is my login controller

```
    class LoginsController < ApplicationController

      def create
       @login = Login.all

      end

    end
```

this is my sessions controller

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user, only: [:home, :profile, :setting]
      before_filter :save_login_state, only: [:login, :login_attempt]

      def login
        @page_title = "LoginUser | Entrar"
      end

      def login_attempt
        authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:nim_as_login], params[:login_password])
        if authorized_user
          session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
          flash[:notice] = "Benvindo de volta #{authorized_user.apelido}"
          redirect_to user_path
        else
          flash.now[:error] = "Email ou palavra passe inválida!"
          render 'sessions/login'
        end
      end

      def home
      end

      def profile
      end

      def setting
      end

      def logout
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to sessions_path
      end
    end
```

My question is, can i store the encrypted password and the user on different tables?

Comment: can you paste your code? and describe a question properly what you want

Comment: what do you mean you tried to to make relation. there must an established relation between user and login. then see `nested_form` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and make form with nested fields. and boom you're done

Comment: thanks for the quick answers, i have just started on both ruby and rails. just posted most of my code. this is an ongoing project so it lacks some code.

Comment: If you are new to RoR, have you considered using gems like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (for user authentication), [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) (for user roles) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (for user authorization). Maybe you could look into these, since they will help you save a lot of time instead of having to build everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks zamakkat, i have considered using some of those gems, but im not the only one working on this project, and one of the goals my boss/co-worker, had for us, was to not use any gems for user authentication.